# Changes in appsettings.json do not reflect after restarting site in the IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am using an appsettings.json file to store the dynamic parameters of my API. When I change a value in appsettings.json file, and start the Site, it doesn't load the new value from json file. I am using the Static variable to read the Value from the Appsettings.json. I am reading the Config value in Startup.cs class. Please some one help, Why the static values not reset after restart the Sites.

**Reading AppSettings.json in Startup**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{ 
     services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration); 
     connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];   
     Time = Configuration["AppSettings:Time"]; 
}
```

Comment: I think it should not be problem with static, since you restarted the application. Though silly, but did you cross check if updated `AppSettings.json` re-deployed? Else please post some sample code for quick understanding.

Comment: Yes, I am Cross Checked AppSettings file.
This is My ConfigureServices Method in the Startup Class to read the values:

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
            connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
            Time = Configuration["AppSettings:Time"];
        }

Comment: And also i would like conform whether the Startup.cs called each time when i restart the Site.

Comment: If you are using Asp.Net Core 1.1 and above you can use `IOptionsSnapshot` to reload config data if config file is modified. You can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration).

Comment: I will try this one. Is Startup.cs called each time when i restart the Site

Comment: Restarting will call into startup.cs. If you restart the site, the updated app setting should be loaded by default.

Comment: Chages are reflected once i restart the Application Pool. Thank you for the Update siva.